# Calculate Average Time Over 24 hour period

Tags: sql, time, average, teradata

I'm working in Teradata and am trying to calulate the average time a job completes.

Data Values:

```
Job Name            Start Date  End Date    End Time
D_BDW_CCIP_SRM_LD   10/10/2012  10/11/2012  01:41:49
D_BDW_CCIP_SRM_LD   10/9/2012   10/10/2012  00:19:56
D_BDW_CCIP_SRM_LD   10/8/2012   10/8/2012   23:37:18
D_BDW_CCIP_SRM_LD   10/5/2012   10/5/2012   23:39:47
D_BDW_CCIP_SRM_LD   10/4/2012   10/4/2012   23:42:47
D_BDW_CCIP_SRM_LD   10/3/2012   10/3/2012   23:41:54
```

The average is coming back with 16:07 instead of 00:07.  What I need to happen is that the calculations where the job finishes next day understands that the time expanded.

In Excel I could do this by adding one day to the end time and then averaging and displaying as a time.

How do I do this in Teradata?

Comment: Are you looking for the average duration for the job to execute or the median end time for the jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick, but I'd be interested in seeing if there is another way.

```
SELECT job_name,
    case when avg_end_time_in_minutes  > 60*24 then avg_end_time_in_minutes - 60*24 
         else avg_end_time_in_minutes end as avg_adjusted,
case when max_end_time_in_minutes  > 60*24 then max_end_time_in_minutes - 60*24 
     else max_end_time_in_minutes end as max_adjusted,
CAST((CAST(avg_adjusted / 60  AS INTEGER) (FORMAT '9(2)')) AS CHAR(2))||':'||
CAST((CAST((avg_adjusted / 60 MOD 1)*60  AS INTEGER) (FORMAT '9(2)')) AS CHAR(2)) 
                        avg_adjusted_time,
CAST((CAST(max_adjusted / 60  AS INTEGER) (FORMAT '9(2)')) AS CHAR(2))||':'||
CAST((CAST((max_adjusted / 60 MOD 1)*60  AS INTEGER) (FORMAT '9(2)')) AS CHAR(2)) 
                           max_adjusted_time
FROM (
SELECT job_name,
    AVG(end_time_in_minutes) avg_end_time_in_minutes,
    MAX(CAST(end_time_in_minutes AS DECIMAL(8,2))) max_end_time_in_minutes
FROM (
SELECT job_name,
    CAST(substr(end_time, 1, 2) AS INTEGER)*60
        + CAST(substr(end_time, 4, 2) AS INTEGER) 
        + cast(end_date - start_date as integer)*60*24 AS end_time_in_minutes
FROM dabank_prod_ops_tb.bdw_tables_load_tracker_view a          
WHERE a.status = 'COMPLETED' 
AND a.start_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 31 AND CURRENT_DATE -1
AND a.end_time IS NOT NULL
) a
GROUP BY 1
) b
```

Answer (score 1):

This is such an interesting question!  **UPDATED with correct syntax:**  Assuming your START_DATE and END_DATE are `DATE` values and END_TIME is a `TIME` value, here is a solution:

```
select cast( avg( case
                  when start_date <> end_date
                  then extract(second from end_time)
                     + extract(minute from end_time) * 60 
                     + extract(hour   from end_time) * 3600
                     + 86400
                  else extract(second from end_time) 
                     + extract(minute from end_time) * 60 
                     + extract(hour   from end_time) * 3600
                  end) mod 86400) as decimal(10,4))
      * INTERVAL '00:00:01.00' HOUR TO SECOND as avg_time
from   your_table
```

The `CASE` expression "adds" one day (86,400 seconds) as you suggested when using Excel to determine the average seconds since midnight into an intermediate result and converted into a `TIME` column.

To be fair, I received help from the [Teradata Forum](http://www.teradataforum.com) formatting the result, but I like this so much I'll be using it myself.

Answer (score 0):

First, figure out the number of seconds that the end time is from midnight on the start date. We can then use that to calculate the average number of seconds taken, and then add that to midnight to find the average end time.

```
select
    avg(extract(second from end_time) + 60 *
        (extract(minute from end_time) + 60 *
        (extract(hour from end_time) + 24 *
        (end_date - start_date))) as avg_duration_in_seconds
    cast(avg_duration_in_seconds / 60 / 60 as integer) as avg_hours
    mod(cast(avg_duration_in_seconds / 60 as integer), 60) as avg_minutes
    mod(cast(avg_duration_in_seconds as integer), 60) as avg_seconds,
    cast('00:00:00' as time) +
        cast(avg_hours as interval hour) +
        cast(avg_minutes as interval minute) +
        cast(avg_seconds as interval second) as avg_end_time
from my_table
```

Be aware though that if the average ends up over 24 hours, avg_end_time will be something like `00:01:15` rather than `24:01:15`.